# Did Long Query Containing With AND is good

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

As My question title i wants to ask that a bigger, very bigger query containing lots of **AND** Keyword is good.
My query is as follow

```
SELECT * FROM `register` 
WHERE id != 0 
AND std = '1' 
AND city = '2' 
AND board = '2' 
AND school_name = '1' 
AND surname Like '%fdsg%'or middlename Like '%fdsg%'or lastname Like '%fdsg%' 
AND stay_alert_checkbox = '1' 
AND dmit_checkbox = '1' 
AND data_resorces = '2' 
AND datetime LIKE '%2018-02-07%' 
AND student_mobile = '9879879879' 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

This Works Fine Now on local server. query produce as user select filters i gave . so if user selects all filters this query is generate

**And PHP Code is**

```
if(!empty($standard)){
  $join .= " AND std = '".$standard."' ";
}

if(!empty($search_city)){
  $join .= " AND city = '".$search_city."' "; 
}

if (!empty($search_board)) {
  $join .= " AND board = '".$search_board."' "; 
}
AND SO ON.............
```

So is it good on server ?

Comment: Did you missing brackets around `OR` keyword? `AND (surname Like '%fdsg%'or middlename Like '%fdsg%'or lastname Like '%fdsg%')`

Comment: Yes i m missing....!!  is it good practice  ??

Comment: Yes I think. Better readability, avoid possible errors.

Comment: Doesn't the student mobile test make the rest redundant?